# Punctuating questions containing questions

Tags: punctuation, questions, question-mark, sentence-ends, end-punctuation

For example,

> ‘Did you just ask, “Why me?”?’, Rita Queried

I know using two question marks is not right, but is this sentence right? Because both are questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When a question is nested within a question: two question marks?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270930/when-a-question-is-nested-within-a-question-two-question-marks) @deadrat's answer wisely begins 'This is a matter of style, so consult your style guide, either the one you've adopted or the one thrust upon you.' They go on to recommend the CMoS advice. But 'I know using two question marks is not right' is an arrogation rather ...

Comment: than divine Truth. I've found a style guide sanctioning double punctuation (more tolerated in the UK than the US) to maintain clarity / accuracy, and Grice sanctions this (and I use the practice) ... though a workaround (rephrasing) is usually preferable. Though here, using a single question mark to do 'double duty' does not compromise either clarity _or_ accuracy. CMoS advises the retention of the inner question mark. // Contrast "Have you read 'Remember Me?'?" (Kinsella's book has the question mark in the title.)