# Where to put the periods: full parenthetical sentence at end of sentence?

Tags: punctuation, parentheses, periods

I [already know](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13528/where-to-put-the-periods-when-using-a-parenthetical-sentence) where to put the period when there is a note in parentheses at the end of a sentence. However, I would like to know what to do in the case where there is a full sentence, or multiple sentences, inside the parentheses contained at the end of a sentence. For example:

`This is a sentence (I am also a sentence. This is yet another sentence.).`

Note the `.).` at the end. Is this correct?

Comment: No, don't double up like that. If the construct inside the parenthesis is deserving of it's own full stop, put the period inside; otherwise put the (one and only) period outside.

Comment: General guideline: Never more than two punctuation marks consecutively, and never double up the same punctuation mark.

Comment: So what is the proper way to format my example sentence? You're free to leave an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I would have to go look up a style reference to make a proper answer. In your example just type *This is a sentence. (I am also a sentence. This is yet another sentence.)*

Comment: Her is a more complicated example: *I am a very long-winded (This explains long-winded.) and complicated parenthezied sentence.*

Comment: That's also useful to know.

Comment: Partial reference: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/when-etc-is-at-the-end-of-a-phrase-do-you-place-a-period-after-it

Comment: Even if you found the correct, grammatical way to write such a sentence, why would you want *that*?

Comment: How is this a duplicate? I included a link to the question it was marked as a duplicate of stating that the linked question didn't fully answer my question, and then went to clearly explain how my question was different.

Comment: It's not really a duplicate.